# Java Resfull web service using Apache CFX

Tags: rest, interface

Can some one post an example of using Rest Webservice that implements 
multiple interfaces using Apache CFX. Below is an example. It works for only add() method when tried to invoke method from second interface it throws 404 error.

```
@path("calculator")
public calc implements addcalc, subcalc{

    public int add(){}

    public int sub(){}

}

@path("add")

interface addcalc{
    @path("add")
    public int add();

}

@path("plus")

interface subcalc{

    @Path("minus")
    public int mins();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

sub is not overriding mins and sub is not annotated with Path. Also, http method is missing which means it is not a resource method but a resource locator.